# When unique value can’t be used practically as a primary key in a database

Tags: sql, database-design, primary-key, unique-key

I am having trouble answering the following question...

> Illustrate **by an example** a scenario where an attribute has unique values in the different rows, yet it can’t be used practically as a primary key in the database relations/tables.

Comment: If the column that's unique is 1000 characters long, it probably isn't sensible to use it as the primary key as 1000-character foreign keys will be unwieldy at best.

Comment: Please read [ask], hits googling 'stackexchange homework' & the voting arrow mouseover texts. Show what you are able to do & relevant summary of your research.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler That's what indexes are for.

Comment: What's "value" mean? (Does it include NULL?) What's "unique value in the different rows" mean? (SQL sense where 2 NULLs are each unique or math sense where NULL=NULL?) What's "PK" mean? (Relational distinguished CK or SQL distinguished UNIQUE NOT NULL?) What's "practically" mean? ("In a SQL DBMS"?) What's the context of this? (Textbook name & edition & section would be helpful.) (If you don't know what words mean, you aren't asking a question when using them.) It's good you tagged this with SQL if that's part of the context, but even there whether "value" includes NULL must be said explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

If the suggested column that has unique values is `nullable` and contains `null` values too, it cannot be a practical primary key. Because primary keys can't be `null`.

Answer (score 0):

A non-sequential GUID is a bad candidate for a primary key, when the data is stored ordered by that key. An insert of a new row will not be appended to the table but must be inserted in the middle, meaning that data must be moved around to make room.

That is why there may also exist sequential GUIDs .

Answer (score 0):

"random" is unique but practically as a key I would not use it.